# How to add notice text above Post Editor?

Tags: editor

I'm trying to add a notice text that said "Please choose a category and add feature Image" text right above the editor so that they don't forget but I'm not sure how to do that so I would be really appreciate if I can get any help.

I've try every method I could find on the internet but it seems like they are a couple of years ago so it's not working for some reason.

I don't want any functionality, I just wanted to show a very simple text above the Title in the text editor so that they don't forget to include category and image.

Comment: are you using gutenberg or classic editor or some other editor all the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using gutenberg you need to use javascript to do this.  Here's the steps I would take.  In your child theme you'll need to add some code.

1. Add a new directory "js".
2. In that directory add a new file called "alerts.js"
3. In that file add this code: (this is the actual warning note)

   ```
   ( function( wp ) {
    wp.data.dispatch('core/notices').createNotice(
        'warning', // Can be one of: success, info, warning, error.
        'Please remember to add a featured image and choose a category.', // Text string to display.
        {
            isDismissible: true, // Whether the user can dismiss the notice.
            // Any actions the user can perform.
        }
    );
    } )( window.wp );
   ```
4. Now tell WordPress that you want to use that code by enqueuing the JS in the child theme's functions.php:

   ```
    function alerts_enqueue() {
        wp_enqueue_script('alerts-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/alerts.js');
    }
    add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'alerts_enqueue' );
   ```

If you're using the classic editor or another block editor this will not work.

> I'd also suggest just requiring the featured image and/or category
> selection if you really want the users abide by the "rules".  :)